# How to wait for different http requests to receive a response (suggestions)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

In my app I need to do a lot of http calls before starting to create some objects...
So only when all the http requests have received the results from the servers, I can process the all the result and construct my page...

To accomplish that I have implemented a method using forkJoin like this:

```
    let req1 = this.http.get<MyObject>('http:/whatever/getData1');
    let req2 = this.http.get<MyObject>('http:/whatever/getData2');
    let req3 = this.http.get<MyObject>('http:/whatever/getData3');
    let req4 = this.http.get<MyObject>('http:/whatever/getData4');

    this.searchSubscription = forkJoin([Observable.of(new Object()), req1,req2,req3,req4]).subscribe(
        results => {
            console.log("data loaded let's start...");
        },
        err =>{
            console.log("Something went worg:" + err);
        }
    );
```

Is that the correct/best way to do it?

Comment: Correct: does it work? Best: how would you determine that?

Comment: I son't get your comment, my code works ...

Comment: Then why are you asking if it's correct? And as for *"best"*, what are your criteria and constraints?

Comment: Again I don't get your comment something can work but can be wrongly implemented...

Comment: My requirements are written in the question (I need to wait for all the responses in order to start to elaborate them all together and construct my page...)

Comment: So if your code **does that**, it's correct. Maybe there are *"better"* ways to write it, but without knowing what better would mean to you how can anyone tell you?

Comment: I think this is a common problem with Angular (and I'm a beginner) so I'm wondering what is best practice to accomplish that...

Comment: Again I'm a java developer if a code works doens't mean that is well programmed... I don't know if you are following my comments...

Comment: This is tedious, so I'm out, but if you have **working code** (and more than just a snippet of it) see [codereview.se].

Comment: nobody forced you to comment...

Answer (score 0):

i think thats not one of the best ways to do it because in the use case of an obeservable you will open an event listener for every subscription and if you do it with forkjoin you wont be able to close all those subscription on the destruction of your component so if i may say you should opt for a better solution like deviding the observables in methods on your service and call them one by one so you will have more visibility and percision in your request or just make a backend route that gives you the data from all of those requests at once

Comment: I see your point, and it's a good one... Thank you for your suggestion. the back-ends are different microservices and I cannot create a new one that merge all the result in one. So if I divide the different calls in different methods at a certain point I have to wait for all the results how do you would implemnt that? again with a ForkJoin or using a different approach?

Comment: i would use 
this.http1subscription = this.service.http1.subscribe(http1 => {
this.http2subscription = this.service.http2.subscribe(http2 => {
 ...
})
})

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is convert the observables to promises and use Promise.all.

```
  let req1 = this.http.get<MyObject>('http:/whatever/getData1').toPromise();
    let req2 = this.http.get<MyObject>('http:/whatever/getData2').toPromise();
    let req3 = this.http.get<MyObject>('http:/whatever/getData3').toPromise();
    let req4 = this.http.get<MyObject>('http:/whatever/getData4').toPromise();

 const [res1,res2,res3,res4] = await Promise.all([req1,req2,req3,req4])
```

Comment: Why you prefer promise to observable, are there any advantages in it? Can you please explain?

Comment: The code is more readable and now I am coding  web components and try to use less external libraries. I continue use observables, but if I could do the same without Rxjs library, prefer do it.